# What factors besides nozzle geometry and propellant's affect engine ISP? How can one optimize ISP?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocketry

In the design of a Rocket engines, it is understandably desirable to have a more efficient engine.

Ensuring the gasses coming out of the engine comes out straight, and the chemistry of the propellants are all straight forward methods of improving ISP, but how can engines with identical propellants and similar nozzles have different specific impulses?

What are the major factors besides nozzle geometry and propellant that allow for higher specific impulses, and how can one optimize an engine to improve specific impulse?

(Obviously I wont compromise other engine parameters for microscopic increases in isp, but I want to build an engine that gets at least 70% efficiency of theoretical Kerosene LOX combustion)

Comment: What textbooks or references have you found so far? So we don't repeat information you already have...

Comment: @SolarMike I own a copy of Modern Engineering for Design of Liquid Propellant Rocket Engines (Huzel, Huang) and Rocket Propulsion Elements (Sutton).  I've mainly been concerned with trajectory prediction using discrete step simulations of the rocket I want to design, and the information on engine optimization is not clear in these books.  I'm mostly looking for the broad strokes of what is most important to an engine, not a bunch of equations on the atomization of propellants (though im sure this is very important for complete combustion).

Comment: So references on the design of con-di nozzles may be relvant...